# how can I build the boost libraries from within the Visual C++ IDE?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-build

The idea is to have a single place in my project, where I'm able to edit compiler/linker settings for the entire final project.
This becomes important, since on x64 there is the problem of mixing AVX and not AVX code.
If this (compiling boost using the Visual C++ IDE) is not possible, where in the boost build system can one change the compiler settings?

PS.
A list of the .cpp files to be compiled with any needed defines would already be sufficient. I don't understand why people think, that a developer cannot start from this (most basic information).

PPS.
Since one of my comments here (explaining my motivation for this question) is gone (potentially deleted by one of the "moderators") I'm adding it here again:
If you do not understand the need for a one-step-build-process, then you should not answer questions here or vote on them.

Comment: You should be able to set compiler options in [`user-config.jam`](http://www.boost.org/build/doc/html/bbv2/overview/configuration.html). I don't even want to start thinking about making a functional visual studio solution for a beast that boost is.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the PS? There are 30+ libraries that get compiled, and perhaps a thousand or so .cpp files (the total is almost 10k, but that includes tests and examples). It just seems impractical to try to reimplement. Script compiling boost in right config (see above). Install to named location ('avx', 'noavx'). Create additional configurations in Visual Studio, so there's one set (Debug,Release,etc.) for avx and another for noavx, and point them to the specific directories.

Comment: You can even modify `rule tag` in `boostcpp.jam` to have the buildsystem name the libraries appropriately (adding `-avx` and `-noavx`), so you don't need to depend on having multiple directories.

Comment: I also don't get why I need a archive library of even a dll for mapping a file into memory for reading. When I implement this, this are just a bunch of classes which only need include files. This is what I ended up doing to avoid external references.

Comment: On my build system I use a python script to build the 3rd party libraries, such as boost, openCV, PCL etc, and use devenv to compile the visual studio projects. The options to build are given in the script. The script is launched by the Jenkins front-end.

Comment: @Dan Mašek: I'm not certain, why I should learn yet another make tool philosophy.  But even if I would: I could in integrate this into a custom build tool in Visual C++. This would require writing a user-config.jam into my home directory for a specific build. Means parallel builds (for different configuration settings) are already out of the question.

Comment: @ExcessPhase Since i deal with dozens of separate components that use many third party libs, boost included, I use dependency management to fetch the right dependencies. Compiling them every time is a horrible waste of time, and often impossible (it's always the same thing, and in many cases i don't have the source). CMake generates correctly configured solution. A script pulls it all together, and publishes the output with dependency info. CI system automates it. Parallel builds just happen in separate directories. The parallelization is just at a higher level.

Comment: If you just use few bits of boost, then you could pull the relevant parts out using bcp, and just toss them in your project, build them with the same flags you use for the rest of the code. Perhaps inspect the .jam files, or run the build once and observe what options they pass to the compiler. It's not entirely clear from your question as to what subset of boost you're interested in. My point was that the whole thing is huge, and from my experience is impractical to recompile frequently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simple.. Boost is made up of C++ source and header files. Hence:

1. Add the Boost root directory to your include paths.
2. For any libraries that you use and have *.cpp source files just add those source files to your project.
3. Look at the Boost build files (Jamfiles) for the libraries and add the usually minimal set of defines they want. Most times there's nothing to add.

And that's it.

Answer (score 1):

Build the libraries using Boost's JAM build system. Much of Boost are headers files that don't need to be explicitly linked, but if you need to(threading library, system, etc...) statically link to those .libs in Visual C++.

Comment: how would this give me a single place for editing all the compiler/linker settings and rerun a rebuild?

Comment: You build the Boost libraries one time to get the set of .libs. Then in Visual C++ you'd pick which .libs you want to link to.

Answer (score 0):

> This becomes important, since on x64 there is the problem of mixing AVX and not AVX code.

There is no problem mixing AVX and SSE code, as long as the AVX code is properly written (i.e. clears the upper 128 bits of the ymm registers before entering the SSE code). And there's nothing special about x64 with regard to SSE and AVX interaction.

> If this (compiling boost using the Visual C++ IDE) is not possible, where in the boost build system can one change the compiler settings?

Even if theoretically possible, this would be an enormously difficult undertaking. Building Boost involves a number of checks, each of which basically means compiling and possibly running a test program. These checks then influence on the Boost compilation. I don't think this is possible to reproduce in a Visual Studio project.

In order to specify command line arguments when building Boost you can use `cxxflags`, `cflags` and `linkflags` options (see [here](http://www.boost.org/build/doc/html/bbv2/overview/invocation.html#bbv2.overview.invocation.properties)), for example:

```
b2 variant=release "cxxflags=/arch:AVX" stage
```

Comment: OK -- I know how to insert this VZEROUPPER. The problem is how do you insert it into code, which is compiled without AVX as the AVX code might call into the rest of the code. No -- this is all too much hussle. I don't believe that you actually did this for a complex project with dlls and child processes. But it is easier just to deny the motivation of the questioner if you yourself never had to deal with the problem, right?

Comment: and the results of these checks change over time? Or they are something like the configure related to autobuild/libtool/maketool? So I could have these checks run once and create my project from them?

Comment: I remember getting some boost-book documentation from one of the boost developers. The next thing I remember that I wasted multiple hours trying to get boost-book (or quick-book) build (on LINUX) and finally gave up. This was some years ago -- today it might be different.

Comment: Do you have any experience how much VZEROUPPER at every boundary slows down the computation or are you just floating this? I've yet to see a complex project using this.

Comment: Yes, I've had large projects with manual SIMD-optimized performance-critical parts. And yes, we did use VZEROUPPER/VZEROALL where needed. Thing is, you don't want to call *any* code from your optimized loops. If you absolutely have to then you must use the instructions anyway because the rest of the system, including C and C++ runtime libraries, are compiled with the assumption of SSE and not AVX. VZEROUPPER/VZEROALL are much much cheaper than the penalty of AVX-to-SSE transition without them. IIRC, both instructions take about 1 cycle, so they are basically free.

Comment: The checks made by Boost.Build are specific to a particular build configuration, which includes the compiler, the OS and possibly even compiler options. Boost.Build caches the results of these checks, sometimes not differentiating enough between the different configs. I guess you could use these cached results to build Boost in your project.

Comment: Also, I don't care about your motivation and whether you actually decide to do what you want. I just answered the parts of your question that I can, to the best of my knowledge. With the attitude you're showing, I probably shouldn't have done this.

Comment: if you do not care about my motivation (which was part of the question) -- why did you answer here? Note that I did not ask how to call bootstrap.*!

Comment: I'm still curious what makes people so much averse against just thinking about this subject or asking a question. "How dare you think about doing things different than other people!"